# Split string into 2 parts with caret

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I have an input field wherein a user can type an expression to represent a power like: `2^5`.

I am using the following code to attempt to split this string with the caret and then evaluate the power with `Math.pow()`:

```
var display = $('#disp').val();
var values = display.split('^');
console.log(values);

var base = values[0];
var exponent = values[1];

var powerCalc = Math.pow(values[0],values[1]);
```

However the console returns this:

```
Array [ "2", "" ]
```

and the expression, regardless of the base, always evaluates to 1 (which makes sense). That said, how can I alter this code to store the second value in this array via `split()`?

Note: I have tried limiting the number of splits to 2 and the console returned the same thing.

I should note also, that I am using a button to add the caret (if that makes a difference) via this function:

```
function addChar(input, character) {
  if (input.value == null || input.value == "0"){
    input.value = character}
  else{
    input.value += character}
};

$('#button-power').click(function(){
    addChar(this.form.display, '^');
});
```

And this to display the result on click:

```
$('#button-enter').click(function(){
    $('#disp').val(powerCalc);
 });
```

The script for the form contains this function as well:

```
function checkNum(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var ch = str.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (ch < "0" || ch > "9") {
      if (ch != "/" && ch != "*" && ch != "+" && ch != "-" && ch != "." && ch != "(" && ch != ")" && ch != "%" && ch != "^") {
      $('#disp').val("Error");
        return false
      }
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: The code looks good to me.

Comment: `"2^5".split("^")` produces `["2", "5"]` on my end.

Comment: Check this out: **http://i.imgur.com/DxNZqwS.png**. Works fine. Need something more... Can you create a [mcve]?

Comment: Looks fine here too: **http://jsbin.com/fatagirate/edit?html,console,output**

Comment: side note...make sure you do some validation

Comment: I wasn't joking when I said the console returns an array with no second element. It does and I legitimately have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. Looks like your code is working just fine.

```js
$('#calc').click(function () {
  var display = $('#disp').val();
  var values = display.split('^');
  console.log(values);

  var base = values[0];
  var exponent = values[1];

  var powerCalc = Math.pow(values[0],values[1]);
  $('#out').text(powerCalc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="disp" type="text" /><button id="calc">Pow!</button>&nbsp;=&nbsp;<span id="out"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a small console too. This works for me, this way:

```js
$(function () {
  var console = {
    log: function (v) {
      $("#console").append('Console: ' + v + "\n");
      window.console.log(v);
    }
  }
  $("#sub").click(function () {
    var display = $('#disp').val();
    var values = display.split('^');
    console.log(values);

    var base = values[0];
    var exponent = values[1];

    var powerCalc = Math.pow(values[0],values[1]);
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI;}
#console {position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 100px; overflow: auto; font-family: consolas; background: #ccc; border-top: 1px solid #999; margin: 0; font-size: 10pt;}
#console strong:first-child {background: #eee; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; display: block; padding: 3px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="disp"><input type="submit" value="Calc" id="sub" />
<pre id="console"><strong>Console:</strong></pre>
```